# I have a metric, I need to find the curvature. How do I continue?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I have the manifold $ M \times N $, where $ M, N $ are 2-dim manifolds, with coordinates $ (x_1, x_2) $ and $ (x_3, x_4) $ respecrively. On $ M\times N $ i have the metric

$
g(\mathbb x, \mathbb x') =
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi(\mathbb x) & 0 \\
0 & \psi(\mathbb x')
\end{bmatrix}
$

So
$
ds^2_{M\times N} = ds^2_M+ds^2_N
$

$
ds^2_{M\times N}(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) =
$

$
= \phi_{11} dx_1^2 + \phi_{22}dx_2^2+2\phi_{12}dx_1dx_2 +
$

$
+ \psi_{33}dx_3^2+\psi_{44}dx_4^2 + 2\psi_{34}dx_3dx_4
$

The curvature is
$
R_{ijkl}\\
$

I know by symmetry that
$
R_{11ks} = R_{22ks} = R_{33ks} = R{44ks} = 0
$

$
R_{ij11} = R_{ij22}=R_{ij33} = R_{ij44} = 0
$

Then

$
R_{ijks} = -R_{jiks}
$

$
R_{ijks} = -R_{ijsk}
$

So
$
R_{jiks} = R_{ijsk}
$

which implies

$
R_{ijks} = R_{ksij} = R_{ksji}
$

Now, if $ i=k $ and $ j=s $,

$
R_{ijij} = -R_{ijji} = R_{jiji} = - R_{jiij}
$

So the first 6 independent symbols to calculate are

$
R_{1212} \quad R_{1313} \quad R_{1414}
$

$
R_{2323} \quad R_{2424} \quad R_{3434}
$

The other 14 independent symbols are
$
R_{1213} \quad R_{1214} \quad R_{1223}$

$
R_{1224} \quad R_{1234} \quad R_{1314}
$

$
R_{1323} \quad R_{1324} \quad R_{1334} 
$

$
R_{1423} \quad R_{1434} \quad R_{2324}
$

$
R_{3423} \quad R_{3424}
$

I am not sure whether all those symbols i wrote are the correct independent ones.
I know the formula for Christoffel symbols, then I need to calculate all those 20 symbols, but I know most of them will be zero. Am I doing good? Because i think i am overdoing and making mistakes.

EDIT ($\textbf{about Christoffel's symbols and sectional curvature}$):

Considering the symmetries $ \Gamma_{aij} = \Gamma_{aji}  $, we need to calculate the following Christoffel symbols:

$
\Gamma_{111} \quad \Gamma_{112} \quad \Gamma_{122} \quad \Gamma_{211} \quad \Gamma_{212} \quad \Gamma_{222}
$

$
\Gamma_{333} \quad \Gamma_{334} \quad \Gamma_{344} \quad \Gamma_{433} \quad \Gamma_{434} \quad \Gamma_{444}
$

$
\Gamma_{111} = \partial_1g_{11}/2 \quad \Gamma_{112} =\partial_2g_{11}/2\quad
\Gamma_{122} =
(2\partial_2g_{12} - \partial_{1}g_{22})/2
$

$
\Gamma_{211} = (2\partial_1g_{21} - \partial_2g_{11})/2 \quad
\Gamma_{212} = \partial_1g_{22}/2
\quad
\Gamma_{222} = \partial_2 g_{22} /2
$

$
\Gamma_{333} = \partial_3g_{33}/2 \quad \Gamma_{334} = \partial_4g_{33}/2 \quad
\Gamma_{344} = (2\partial_4g_{34} - \partial_{3}g_{44})/2
$

$
\Gamma_{433} = (2\partial_3g_{43} - \partial_4g_{33})/2 \quad
\Gamma_{434} = \partial_3g_{44}/2
\quad
\Gamma_{444} = \partial_4 g_{44}/2 
$

And what about the sectional curvature $S$?
Being $M, N$ bidimensional, we only have one tangent plane, so one sectional curvature. In dimension 2, we know that the Ricci tensor coincides with the sectional curvature.

EDIT II ($\textbf{forgot to add metric symbols}$):

For $M$:

$
S(e_1, e_2) = \frac{Ric(e_1, e_1) + Ric(e_2, e_2)}{2}
$

$
Ric(e_1, e_1) = g(R(e_1, e_1)e_1,e_1) + g(R(e_1, e_2)e_2, e_1) =
$

$
= R^1_{111}g_{11} + R^2_{111}g_{21} + R^1_{122}g_{11} + R_{122}^2g_{21}
$

$
Ric(e_2, e_2) =
$

$
= g(R(e_2, e_1)e_1,e_2) + g(R(e_2, e_2)e_2, e_2)
$

$
= R^1_{211}g_{12} + R^2_{211}g_{22} + R^1_{222}g_{12} + R^2_{222}g_{22} =
$

This implies
$
S(M) =
$

$
= \frac{g_{11}}{2}(R^1_{111} + R^1_{122}) + \frac{g_{22}}{2}(R^2_{211} + R^2_{222})
$

$
+\frac{g_{12}}{2}(R^2_{111} + R^2_{122} + R^1_{222} + R^1_{211})
$

Similarly for $ N $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R^{M}$ be the Riemann curvature of $M$, and $R^{N}$ be the Riemann curvature of $N$. Since you have just a product manifold where the $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(x_3,x_4)$ coordinates are independent, the resulting Riemann curvature has the property:

$$R_{abcd} (x,x')=\\= \begin{cases} R^{M}_{abcd}(x)\quad \text{if} \quad \{a,b,c,d\}\subset\{1,2\} \\
 R^{N}_{abcd}(x')\quad \text{if} \quad \{a,b,c,d\}\subset\{3,4\} \\
0 \quad \text{in any other case (that is,} \\
\quad\; \text{ when indices come from both subspaces.)}
\end{cases}$$

You still need to compute the Riemann curvature of the $2$-dimensional $M$ and $N$ submanifolds, but it's easier than working in the full $4$-dimensional manifold.

An informal justification for the above would be that [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) of a vector from the $M$ component of the tangent space along a curve formed in the $N$ component leaves it unchanged. Any change in the $M$-components of a vector must come from movement along the $M$-subspace.

Comment: So the only two terms i have to calculate are $R_{1212}$ and $R_{3434}$. I still have troubles with the Christoffel's symbols. Now I have the formula for the $\Gamma_{ijk}$:


$
\Gamma_{ijk} = \frac{
\partial_k(g_{ij}) + \partial_j(g_{ik}) - \partial_i(g_{jk})
}{2}
$

But, still, there are 8 Christoffels for $\{1, 2\}$ and 8 for $\{3, 4\}$?

Comment: Yes. There are $8$ index components for the $2D$ Christoffel symbol, tough with symmetry you see there are $6$ independent ones.  The symmetry is specifically $\Gamma_{ijk} = \Gamma_{ikj}$, giving  $\Gamma_{a12} = \Gamma_{a21}$ for $a\in\{1,2\}$. So you still need to compute $2*6 = 12$ components ($6$ for$ \{1,2\}\;$ and $6$ for $\{3,4\}$).

Comment: I edited the post calculating explicitly the Christoffels and I added a section about sectional curvature. Hope it's correct.

Comment: The contractions for getting the Ricci tensor don't look correct (only works when $g$ is identity) . We have $R_{ac} = R_{abcd}g^{bd}$ so the terms of the inverse metric tensor have to appear in the formula.

 By normalizing with the metric when computing the sectional curvature you can get   $K^{M} = \frac{R_{1212}}{g_{11}g_{22}-g_{12}^2}$ for the sectional curvature of $M$ and then you can write $R_{ab} = K^{M} g_{ab}$ when $\{a,b\}\subset\{1,2\}$ 

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature
and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Surfaces

Comment: We have
$R_{11} =  R_{1111}g^{11} +  R_{1121}g^{12}  + R_{2111}g^{21}   + R_{2121}g^{22} = R_{1212}g^{22}$
Trough a similar computation you can get: 
$R_{12} =  R_{2112}g^{21}$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot to add the metric terms. But, isn't it this way?

$
S(e_1, e_2) = (Ric(e_1, e_1) + Ric(e_2, e_2))/2
$
;
$
Ric(e_1, e_1) = g(R(e_1, e_1)e_1,e_1) + g(R(e_1, e_2)e_2, e_1) =
$

$
= R_{1111}g_{11} + R_{1112}g_{21} + R_{1221}g_{11} + R_{1222}g_{22}
$

$
= R_{1221}g_{11}
$

Comment: $
\\Ric(e_2, e_2) =
$

$
= g(R(e_2, e_1)e_1,e_2) + g(R(e_2, e_2)e_2, e_2)
$

$
 = R_{2111}g_{12} + R_{2112}g_{22} + R_{2221}g_{12} + R_{2222}g_{22} =
$

$
R_{2112}g_{22}
$

$\implies$

$
S(M) = (R_{1221}g_{11} + R_{2112}g_{22})/2 = R_{1221}\frac{g_{11}+g_{22}}{2}
$

Comment: Contraction must be made with the inverse (contra-variant) metric, not the normal one (use $g^{12}$ instead of $g_{12}$).
Their relationship is that $\begin{pmatrix}
g^{11} & g^{12}\\
g^{21} & g^{22}
\end{pmatrix}$ 
 is the matrix inverse of
$\begin{pmatrix}
g_{11} & g_{12}\\
g_{21} & g_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Maybe I just make this mistake, I am using Riemann tensor, so the components must be written as $R^i_{jks}$. So, for example, it is
$
Ric(e_1, e_1) = R^1_{211}g_{12} + R^2_{211}g_{22} + R^1_{222}g_{12} + R^2_{222}g_{22}
$

Comment: Contraction always works between covariant-components (upper indices) and contra-variant components (lower indices). The metric tensor $g_{ab}$ and its inverse $g^{ab}$ are used to raise or lower indices so you can make contractions. Eg. you can't contract $R_{ab}$ but you can contract $R_{ab}g^{bc}$.

Comment: If you're using the $(3,1)$ Riemann tensor $R^{a}_{bcd}$ (some prefer to use the $(4,0)$ one $R_{abcd}$ because it has more symmetries ), then you already have $1$ covariant and $1$ contra-variant index. You don't need to add the metric when contracting:  $Ric(e_1, e_1) = R^{1}_{111}+ R^{2}_{121} = R^{2}_{121}$. Here is a formula for the $(4,0)$ Riemann tensor:
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f8ba301d7a206384db33b7303b1a19a020f3fe21
Here is a formula for the $(3,1)$ one:
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/97f07269279b9e67d9b28123e5d830f0463b7976

Comment: They are related by $R^{a}_{bcd} = g^{ax}R_{xbcd}$. So for example $R^{1}_{212} = g^{11} R_{1212} +  g^{12} R_{2212} = g^{11} R_{1212} $

Comment: Then, why use $g$ in the formula of $Ric$? I am just using a bilinear form on two vectors.

Comment: You use $g^{ab}$ if you start with the $(4,0)$ tensor $R_{abcd}$ . I assumed you did because you've written indices as $R_{1212}$ and not $R^{1}_{212}$.  The complete formula is $R_{bd} = R^{a}_{bad} = R_{xbyd}g^{xy}$. So the $g$ part only appears when you use the $(4,0)$ Riemann  tensor, to balance the indices. But you have to keep track of which version you are using and write the indices correctly. The same goes for Christoffel symbols of the first and second kind (they should not be confused).

Comment: You still need to multiply by $g^{ab}$ to get the Christoffel symbols of the second kind that are used in  the formula for the $(3,1)$ Riemann tensor.  You have $\Gamma^a_{bc} = g^{ax}\Gamma_{xbc}$, so for example $\Gamma^{1}_{12} = g^{11} \Gamma_{112}  +g^{12}  \Gamma_{212}$.

Comment: $
R_{12} = R^1_{112}g_{11} + R^2_{112}g_{21} + R^1_{212}g_{21} + R^2_{212}g_{22} = R_{1112} + R_{2212} = 0
$

$
R_{21} = R^1_{121}g_{11} + R^2_{121}g_{21} + R^1_{221}g_{12} + R^2_{221}g_{22} = R_{1121} + R_{2221} = 0
$

$
R_{11} = R^1_{111}g_{11} + R^2_{111}g_{21} + R^1_{211}g_{12} + R^2_{211}g_{22} = R_{1111} + R_{2211} = 0
$

$
R_{22} = R^1_{122}g_{11} + R^2_{122}g_{21} + R^1_{222}g_{12} + R^2_{222}g_{22} = R_{1122} + R_{2222} = 0
$

Comment: I finally understood where my mistake was, and now I obtained that the Ricci tensor is identically zero. So is the sectional curvature and the scalar curvature.

Comment: Those still don't look correct. To check validity, the difference between the number of lower indices and the number of upper indices must be the same on both sides of the equation (the contraction rule is cancel upper with lower). So you have:  
$R_{ab} = R^{x}_{axb}=R_{xayb}g^{xy}$. We set $a=1,b=1$ and sum trough all the other possible values for $x$ and $y$. We get:
$R_{11} =  R^1_{111} +  R^2_{121} =  R^2_{121} $
$R_{11} = R_{1111}g^{11} + R^{1121}g^{12} + R_{2111}g^{21} + R_{2121}g_{22} = R_{2121}g^{22}$
So we get: $R_{11} =  R^2_{121} = R_{2121}g^{22}$
It is true that $R_{12}=0$.

Comment: We have on the left side $2$ lower indices ($R_{ab}$) and the right side either $3$ lower and $1$ upper index ($R^{a}_{bcd}$) or $4$ lower and $2$ upper indices. ($R_{xaby}g^{xy}$). Notice that $2 = 3-1 = 4-2$. You can only contract upper with lower, so the difference stays constant.

Comment: At this point I am writing the $R^i_{jks} $ components of the Riemann tensor wrong.